# Break value within list into tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I created a list/series from a dataframe function. It's one long list of value like this:

```
print(a)

AABA     0.001028
AAL      0.000975
AAME    -0.000056
AAPL    -0.000749
AAWW     0.000311
....
```

I'd like to break this long list of content into tuples like `[AABA, 0.001028],[AAL, 0.000975]`,...etc. I tried the `split()` function but got the error of a list not having split attribute.

I also tried this:

```
list=a
list = list[0].split(" ")
```

The error msg was `'Series' object has no attribute 'split'`

What to do?

Comment: Tuples have `() ` not `[]`

Comment: you've got a pandas series in your list. The values are already probably splitted. Have you tried `print(a[0])`

Comment: Yes tried. I can see the values but I need the them broken up into tuples so i can call the values out separately in later functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is actually a Pandas Series where `AABA`... is the index, turn the Series to a dict then get the items in the dict.:

```
>>> s
0
AABA    0.001028
AAL     0.000975
AAME   -0.000056
AAPL   -0.000749
AAWW    0.000311
Name: 1, dtype: float64

>>> items = s.to_dict().items()
>>> list(items)
[('AABA', 0.0010279999999999998), ('AAL', 0.000975), ('AAME', -5.6000000000000006e-05), ('AAPL', -0.000749), ('AAWW', 0.00031099999999999997)]
>>> for item in items:
    print(item)

('AABA', 0.0010279999999999998)
('AAL', 0.000975)
('AAME', -5.6000000000000006e-05)
('AAPL', -0.000749)
('AAWW', 0.00031099999999999997)
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

convert series object into list using `.tolist()` [refer doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html)

```
v = df['col1'].tolist()

[i.split(" ") for i in v]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
AABA = 0.001028
AAL = 0.000975
AAME = -0.000056
AAPL = -0.000749
AAWW = 0.000311

myList = [AABA, AAL, AAME, AAPL, AAWW]
print(myList)
```

Comment: Do you mean to add the "="? It's a long list - unless there is a way to add it to each. My problem now is that the value is in one big lump.

Comment: for example, AABA is a variable. without the '=' you dont set the value. then after all of the variables have been created, you add them to a list, in this case 'myList'

Comment: dont forget to add the tick next to each answer you find helpful.